# Join array using variable separator

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to join an array using `.joined(separator:)`.  However, I want the separator to include the index.  For example, if I have the array `["red", "orange", "yellow", "green"]`, I want the output to be `"red (0), orange (1), yellow (2), green"`.  I tried to do `.joined(separator: "\($0.index), ")`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Is your output a mistake or do you actually not want the `(3)` at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
let array = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green"]

let output = array.enumerated()
    .map { $1 + " (\($0))" }
    .joined(separator: ", ")

print(output)   //red (0), orange (1), yellow (2), green (3)
```

If the last index shouldn't be included, then here is a solution:

```
let output = (array.dropLast().enumerated()
    .map { $1 + " (\($0))" }
    + [array.last ?? ""])
    .joined(separator: ", ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
var arr = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green"]
let num = (0 ..< arr.count - 1).map { " (\($0)), " }
let res = zip(arr,num).map{ $0 + $1 }.joined() + arr.last!
```

Comment: `(0 ..< arr.count - 1)` can also be written as `arr.indices.dropLast()`